# Differentiating between non-existent and un-authorized topic in librdkafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, librdkafka

How can I make sure if a topic is authorized or not ?

I need this because, in my consumer I get the meta data for all the known topics and then do assign call. The metadata call doesn't give the un-authorized topics and non-existent topic. If a topic doesn't exist, I'll create one and if a topic is unauthorized, I have to fail. But I don't have a way to differentiate between non-existent and unauthorized topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try listing all the topics, if the topic exists it will be there in the list. I did not use librdkafka but still from the [link](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/310), the author says the following function should give you (without the topic argument).

```
rd_kafka_metadata()
```

Comment: I'm using this. But this doesn't list the topic if the user I am trying doesn't have authorization on that topic

Comment: Are you able to list the topics using kafkacat tool? Because it also uses librdkafka, I think. If it can, then it should work here also. I doubt, if we require to enter any user for listing the topics.